# HTML5 Canvas line with different color

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am creating a line graph as in the link http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2011/06/draw-a-line-graph-using-html5-canvas/

Here i want to draw line with diff colors, i tried to used beignPath() inbetween the line draw. Here is the piece of code i used

```
c.strokeStyle = '#f00';
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(getXPixel(0), getYPixel(data.values[0].Y));

for(var i = 1; i < data.values.length; i ++) {
    if(i > 2){
        c.strokeStyle = 'green';
        c.beginPath();
    }
    c.lineTo(getXPixel(i), getYPixel(data.values[i].Y));
    c.stroke();
}
```

Actually i'm getting a diff line color, But its missing the starting line stroke with "green" color. Please help me to solve this issue

Any help will be appreciated greatly.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to figure out the issue my self.. I'm posting the fix if anybody needs it in future.. I made a c.moveTo to previous X, Y  values.. and the pblm is fixed..

Comment: Please read this http://html5tutorial.com/advanced-path-painting/#beginPath to understand why you got that problem and why your solution fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$r=100;

$a1=90;
$a1=180-$a1;

$ry=60;
$yb=60;

$a2=180-(90+$ry);
$a3=180-(90+$ry+$yb);

//subtract only x coordinate from x2;
$x=150;
$y=150;

$x1=150-cos(deg2rad($a1))*$r;
$y1=150-sin(deg2rad($a1))*$r;

$x2=150-cos(deg2rad($a2))*$r;
$y2=150-sin(deg2rad($a2))*$r;
$x2e=$x2-tan(deg2rad($a2));
$y2e=((($x2e-$x2)*($y2-$y))/($x2-$x))+$y2;


$x3=150-cos(deg2rad($a3))*$r;
$y3=150-sin(deg2rad($a3))*$r;

echo"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><style>
#i01{
    background color:red;
    width=350;
    height=350;

}

</style></head>
<body>


<canvas id='myCanvas' width='300' height='300' style='border:1px solid #d3d3d3;'  >
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 150, $r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();


//ctx.moveTo(150,150);
//ctx.lineTo(200,150);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo($x,$y);
ctx.lineTo($x1,$y1);
ctx.font = '20px Arial';
ctx.fillText('R',$x1,$y1);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo($x,$y);
ctx.lineTo($x2,$y2);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
ctx.font = '20px Arial';
ctx.fillText('Y',$x2,$y2);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo($x,$y);
ctx.lineTo($x3,$y3);
ctx.font = '20px Arial';
ctx.fillText('B',$x3,$y3);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.stroke();


</script>


</body>
</html>";
?>
```

Comment: PHP is completely unnecessary. And unexplained code dumps are not good answers.